# Hardwire vs Plug-In stationary power tools?

Tags: electrical, tools

I have a large woodworking machine with a 5HP, 240VAC motor, requiring a 30A 240VAC branch circuit. The machine weighs about 1000 lbs and is stationary (not mounted on a mobile base). The machine will have a dedicated branch circuit regardless of the connection method.

Is this machine required to be attached with a plug-and-cord method, or hardwired in with flexible conduit?

Comment: Does it have a plug or does it have a junction or wiring box? If you have the manual, does it prescribe a wiring method?

Comment: If you do hard-wire it in, put in a lockable disconnect.  This is so power can be shut off and locked off when servicing.

Comment: You may want to consider a motor start relay. if power is interrupted while running it won't restart on its' own when power is restored.

Comment: It's got a lock-able disconnect switch on the machine and a latching E-Stop button on the front. The motor is a 3-phase driven by a VFD hooked to single-phase, which already does the duty of a start relay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For stationary equipment you can go hard wire or plug connected. Usually wood working equipment has a high vibration so a 6' length of flexible conduit is used. In my shop I prefer cord connected on most equipment but my big air compressor that is bolted to the floor is flex connected.

Comment: Note that if it gets hard wired, there should be a local disconnect near the machine